# Recursive function inside if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion

for a recursive function like

```
bool recur(int i)
{
     int x = i;
     if (x == 10)
     { 
          return true;
     }
     else
     {  
          x++;
          recur(x);
     }
     return false;
}
```

and use this in if statement

```
if (recur(0))
{
     return true;
}
```

Will the recursion occur inside the if statement until the function returns true?

Comment: Why don't you just write some test code and try it?

Comment: The shown code is not valid and would never compile. You probably mean it as pseudo code, but for that it is not clear enough. I think you can "insert" the second fragment into the first to complete the code. But even better would be providing a [mre].

Comment: @kaylum I had a code that does this but I couldn't tell what was going on.

Comment: The condition of the if statement (`recur()`) needs to return a value before the program can decide which of the branches of the if statement should be executed - it only chooses one branch or the other AFTER the condition of the if statement (`recur()`)  has returned true or false.

Comment: @Yunnosch I see. I will try that.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah What if I have the return false at the end of the function? Would recur() recursively operate inside the if statement?

Comment: Nothing else happens until the recursion stops and recur returns a value.  Only then can the program know what to do with that if statement.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah So will this if statement eventually return true?

Comment: Watch out for the recursion not returning at all - if you pass `recur(11)` you are in trouble.  I would have written `if (x == 10)` as `if (x => 10)`

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah thank you very much!

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I don't think your statement above is correct since there's no `return` when doing the recursion. If it hits the second branch, it will do the recursion until x==10, but it will ignore the result and return false.

Comment: @EdmCoff   Oooo.  Good point.  I'm not sure how I missed that.  I better start again (more carefully)

Comment: @Mardia As was pointed out in the comments I missed something very important. recur will ALWAYS return false to the if statement except when you call `if (recur(10))` The reason is because you never check the return value of recur when it is called inside of the recur function. So (assuming that you aren't using `if (recur(10))`) when recur does return true that is ignored and you do reach the `return false;` so the if statement gets a result of false from recur. And that is opposite the way I read the code the first time around. So maybe you want `return recur(x);` inside the recur function?

Comment: You can see the difference here: https://www.godbolt.org/z/crj8d3

Comment: @EdmCoff why doesn't it return true when x hits 10? I wrote if (x == 10) return true. How come that gets ignored?

Comment: Because you just have `recur(x)` not `return recur(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recur()` returns `true` only if its argument is `10`, otherwise it recurses with an incremented argument and returns `false`:

- `recur(0)` recurses 10 times and returns `false`. All return values from these recursive calls are ignored in the calling code. Hence in `if (recur(0)) return true;` the `return` statement is not executed.
- `recur(10)` returns `true` without recursing.
- `recur(11)` and any greater argument will have undefined behavior: if will cause an infinite recursion, until `x++` causes an arithmetic overflow which has undefined behavior, most probably causing a **stack overflow** well before that.
- a [clever compiler](https://www.godbolt.org/z/qo8qMz) such as `clang` will determine that `recur` is a pure function (a function without side effects) and remove the recursive call completely as the result is ignored, simplifying the code as:

  ```
    bool recur(int i) {
        return (i == 10);
    }
  ```